# How do I copy a code from CodePen to VS Code properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code, copy-paste

I want to copy my codepen to visual studio code, but when I do copy-paste it into visual studio code it is either something wrong or not working or doesn't show the output. but in codepen it works just fine. I did some research on how to link HTML, CSS, and JS from youtube. I followed the video instruction, I link the HTML, CSS, and JS, and downloaded the extension but why is it not working? most are correct (i think) but I think the red-colored codes are wrong, I guess that is the reason my website doesn't work but I don't know how because I'm new and just started in visual studio code, I'm mostly at codepen.

this is my attendance codepen https://codepen.io/rhynacpil/pen/dyKmyLE

attendance HTML in visual studio code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <div class="mistyrose"></div>
    <h1>Attendance</h1>
    
    
    <label for="start">Start month:</label>
    <input type="month" id="start" name="start" min="2018-03" value="2018-05">
    
    <div class="holder">
                        <td>Un/check All</td>
                            <div class="attendance">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll"/>
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
    
    <table id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="name-col">Name</th>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>3</th>
          <th>4</th>
          <th>5</th>
          <th>6</th>
          <th>7</th>
          <th>8</th>
          <th>9</th>
          <th>10</th>
          <th>11</th>
          <th>12</th>
          <th>13</th>
          <th>14</th>
          <th>15</th>
          <th>16</th>
          <th>17</th>
          <th>18</th>
          <th>19</th>
          <th>20</th>
          <th>21</th>
          <th>22</th>
          <th>23</th>
          <th>24</th>
          <th>25</th>
          <th>26</th>
          <th>27</th>
          <th>28</th>
          <th>29</th>
          <th>30</th>
          <th>31</th>
          <th class="missed-col">Days Missed</th>
          <th>Remove</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    
      <input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')">
    
    
      <tbody>
        <tr class="visitor">
          <td class="name-col"><input type="text" placeholder="Your name"></td>
          <td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td class="missed-col">0</td><type="checkbox"></td>
          <td><input type="button" value="(Delete)"></td>
          
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    line-height: 1.9;
    margin: 2em;
    min-width: 1100px;
}

th {
    background-color: #001f3f;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 1em 1.3em;

}

td {
    border-top: 5px solid #eee;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;

}

input {
    cursor: pointer;
}


th.missed-col {
    background-color: #f00;
}



th.Attend-col {
    background-color: #f00;
    
}

td.Attend-col {
    background-color: #ffecec;
    color: #f00;
    text-align: center;
    
}

.name-col {
    text-align: left;
    min-width: 11rem;
  
}

td.missed-col {
    background-color: #ffecec;
    color: #f00;
    text-align: center;
}


input::placeholder {
    font-weight: bold;
    opacity: .5;
    color: black;
}


      .mistyrose {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        position: fixed;
        background-image: linear-gradient(
            216deg,
            rgba(77, 77, 77, 0.05) 0%,
            rgba(77, 77, 77, 0.05) 25%,
            rgba(42, 42, 42, 0.05) 25%,
            rgba(42, 42, 42, 0.05) 38%,
            rgba(223, 223, 223, 0.05) 38%,
            rgba(223, 223, 223, 0.05) 75%,
            rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.05) 75%,
            rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.05) 100%
          ),
          linear-gradient(
            44deg,
            rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.05) 0%,
            rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.05) 34%,
            rgba(212, 212, 212, 0.05) 34%,
            rgba(212, 212, 212, 0.05) 57%,
            rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.05) 57%,
            rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.05) 89%,
            rgba(135, 135, 135, 0.05) 89%,
            rgba(135, 135, 135, 0.05) 100%
          ),
          linear-gradient(
            241deg,
            rgba(55, 55, 55, 0.05) 0%,
            rgba(55, 55, 55, 0.05) 14%,
            rgba(209, 209, 209, 0.05) 14%,
            rgba(209, 209, 209, 0.05) 60%,
            rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.05) 60%,
            rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.05) 69%,
            rgba(164, 164, 164, 0.05) 69%,
            rgba(164, 164, 164, 0.05) 100%
          ),
          linear-gradient(
            249deg,
            rgba(248, 248, 248, 0.05) 0%,
            rgba(248, 248, 248, 0.05) 32%,
            rgba(148, 148, 148, 0.05) 32%,
            rgba(148, 148, 148, 0.05) 35%,
            rgba(202, 202, 202, 0.05) 35%,
            rgba(202, 202, 202, 0.05) 51%,
            rgba(181, 181, 181, 0.05) 51%,
            rgba(181, 181, 181, 0.05) 100%
          ),
          linear-gradient(92deg, rgb(255, 228, 225), rgb(255, 228, 225));
        z-index: -6;
      }
```

Javascript

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[1].cells.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
        switch (newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
            case "text":
                newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                break;
            case "checkbox":
                newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                break;
            case "select-one":
                newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
}



$('table').on('click', 'input[type="button"]', function(e){
   $(this).closest('tr').remove()
})

$("#checkAll").change(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

[image]

this is the output of visual studio code but not working

[image]

this is the output in codepen

[image]

I copy-paste it into visual studio code and link the HTML, CSS, and Javascript, most are correct (i think) but I think the red-colored codes are wrong, I guess that is the reason my website doesn't work but I don't know how because of a lack of knowledge in visual studio code. I'm new to visual studio code.

Comment: The link tag lacks the closing angle bracket.

Comment: Ok, I closed it thank you but how do I solve the red-colored "border"? is it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You of course need to close properly the  tag, but the real problem here is that you are typing the name of the file in the search bar like a website url and that can't work. The simplest (since you have it already installed), and imo nicest, way to see the result of your html and edit it along is to click the "go live" button at the very bottom-right; that will fire up a local server on your computer and every time you save the file the result will automatically load.
Still if you open the "attendance.html" file with a browser you will see the page as you would expect. Lastly you could type `file:///<path_to_the_file>/Attendance.html` to open any browser-compatible file.

Comment: need to close properly the tag? I don't know what tag should I close and I tried click go live but didn't work. I'm really hard time understanding the codes and most of them are from codepen.

Comment: @Joserenzo the "go live" button only works if the html is valid. As you can see vs code is telling you that something is wrong with the red highlight. I can't say what specifically since the view of the code is partial but probably the <script> tag isn't closed (closing a tag means typing </script>) properly. Try copying all the html from code pen and paste it in the <body> of the html

Comment: I post some pictures, is this right or is something else wrong? i haven't tested yet in go live I want to make sure its all correct first

Comment: https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/exporting-pens/ this page frome the CodePen's site explains how to export codepens, try following this. When you open a codepen online, the sites takes care behind the scenes of some things like linking the html to css and js to let you concentrare only on the experiments you are doing. If you just copy the 3 texts you can't make it work just by pasting it in 3 files, you have to add those "behind the scenes" lines, or even better use the export method linked and use the files packed in the .zip file.

Comment: I manage to export it thank you, my attendance is now a website but can I add a database in codepen?

Comment: @Joserenzo no you can't. If you want to have database capabilities you have to set up one separately.

Comment: so I have to make "This attendance" and database in visual studio code? Are there any notes, websites, etc. for beginners like me?

Comment: @Joserenzo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xr6uZDRTna0 watch this the source is good for beginners.

Comment: I will, it's long but this will help me. thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you just write `attendace.html` in the address bar, the page will not open for you. On VS Code, you can install an extension called [live server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer), and follow the instructions, or else, you can just go in the folder where you have
saved your files, and open the `.html` file with any browser.

Comment: okay, I'll install the live server extension and give it a try

Comment: you can refer here as well: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-enable-live-server-on-visual-studio-code/

Comment: I install the live server extension and click "Go live" but it didn't work. It just showed at the top is "~ / and search box" and in the middle is "script.js and style.css". I click the script.js and http://127.0.0.1:5500/script.js showed me "this site can't be reached" Sorry if I didn't understand your instruction.

Comment: Did you try opening the ‘.html’ file directly?

Comment: how? like opening it in the attendance file in the folder? there is google icon with an attendance name on it, I open it, and showed me my attendance but only in HTML, with no design in the CSS, and no function of the buttons (no JS). there is a folder attendance name on it and open it, only the script and style in the VS but no HTML. I wish I could send some pictures to make easier to understand

Comment: I think html file is not present in your `attendance folder`, move the html file in the `attendance` folder with `.js` and `.css` and click `go live`.
Secondly, there are some semantic mistakes in your html file, like no head or body, link tag not closed.
add a head tag and a body tag(search google for semantic structure of html), put only the link tag in your head tag and close the link tag and head tag, open the body tag. put all of your html in there then put the script tag just before you close the body tag, i.e. before `</body>`. I see you've added jquery in your code pen, add it's cdn.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252276/discussion-between-harshit-t-and-jose-renzo).